# Add new category in Menu (Xfce)

Tags: xfce, desktop, menu

I tried doing the following to add a new category named "Electronics" in Whisker Menu on Linux Mint 17.1 with Xfce 4.10.1:

1. I added this text to `~/.config/menus/xfce-applications.menu` just after rest of entries for categories

```
    <Menu>
        <Name>Electronics</Name>
        <Directory>xfce-electronics.directory</Directory>
        <Layout>
            <Merge type="menus" />
            <Filename>geda-gattrib.desktop</Filename>
            <Merge type="files" />
        </Layout>
    </Menu>
```

and

```
<Menuname>Electronics</Menuname>
```

down in the file (with other similar entries).

2. Then, I added `<Menuname>Electronics</Menuname>` to `~/.config/menus/applications.menu` along with similar entries.
3. Last, I made a new file named `~/.local/share/desktop-directories/xfce-electronics.directory` and added wrote the following to it:

```
    [Desktop Entry]
    Type=Directory
    Icon=file-manager
    Name=Electronics
    Comment=
```

However, I am not seeing a new category in either Whisker Menu or Alacarte or Menulibre (menu editors). Is there something else to be done that I missed?

Comment: Have you did: Start -> Properties -> Choose the custom menu option and navigate and select the custom menu file `~/.config/menus/xfce-applications.menu`?

Comment: I tried but I can't find the option- previously, if memory serves, it could be accessed under the title Menu File after right clicking on the WhiskerMenu "icon" and selecting Properties .  Now, in version 1.4.1, it seems that they have removed it from there. Is there anywhere else I can find it?

Comment: If you're using 4.10 or 4.12, then you can edit the Menu using `alacarte` or `menulibre` utilities. The option is here: [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xzUUu.png)

Comment: Application Menu! I was looking in the Whisker Menu's options.

Comment: So, have you resolved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

I made it the same way as you but also added a include tag in `~/.config/menus/xfce-applications.menu`:

```
<Menu>
    <Name>Electronics</Name>
    <Directory>xfce-electronics.directory</Directory>
    <Layout>
        <Merge type="menus" />
        <Merge type="files" />
    </Layout>
    <Include>
        <Category>Electronics</Category>
    </Include>
</Menu>
```

Of course I also added the `~/.local/share/desktop-directories/xfce-electronics.directory` file like you. You can then add desktop files under `~/.local/share/applications` with the category "Electronics".